# Saving an image inside a folder in webcontent

Tags: java

I want to put the user uploadedimage inside the "Images" folder in WebContent..

I tried ..

```
String filePath = request.getContextPath() + "/WebContent/Images/"
                    + userForm.getUploadedFile().getFileName();
```

but its giving a FileNotFound Exception...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \NewStrutsOBL\WebContent\Images\Penguins.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.fulcrum.obl.Action.UserAction.addUser(UserAction.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fulcrum.obl.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please guide on where i am wrong..

Comment: did you try to remove `WebContent` from the path?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open up the file before you've moved it into the folder, if I had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

visit http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29

use `servletContext.getRealPath(path to file);`

Answer (score 0):

WebContenct is not deployed on server as it is only for eclipse. so remove Webcontent from the path and give a try.

Comment: I tried ..still it is giving FileNotFound Exception..why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

filePath contains a relative file and you try to load the filePath using a method where absolute files are required.

Try

```
filePath = servlet.getRealPath("Images/"
                + userForm.getUploadedFile().getFileName());
```